# How to round off a datetime column in pyspark dataframe to nearest quarter

Tags: pyspark

I have a column which has datetime values. Example: 01/17/2020 15:55:00. I want to round off the time to nearest quarter (01/17/2020 16:00:00). Note: please don't answer for this question using pandas i want answer only using pyspark.

Answer (score 1):

try this this will work for you.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import current_timestamp
result = data.withColumn("hour",hour((round(unix_timestamp("date")/3600)*3600).cast("timestamp")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Although in Spark we don't have a sql functions that truncates directly the datetime to a quarter, we can build the column using a bunch of functions.
First, create the DataFrame

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import current_timestamp
dateDF = spark.range(10)\
.withColumn("today", current_timestamp())
dateDF.show(10, False)
```

Then, truncate the minutes that belongs to the next quarter (stroing it in a mins column)

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import minute, hour, col, round, date_trunc, unix_timestamp, to_timestamp
dateDF2 = dateDF.select(col("today"),
              (round(minute(col("today"))/15)*15).cast("int").alias("mins"))
```

Then, we truncate the timestamp to the thour measure, convert it to unix_timestamp, add the minutes for truncation and convert it again to the timestamp type

```
dateDF2.select(col("today"), to_timestamp(unix_timestamp(date_trunc("hour", col("today"))) + col("mins")*60).alias("truncated_timestamp")).show(10, False)
```

Hope this helps